# Where can I find USA ocean port FIPS code?

Tags: usa, geocoding

I am interested in all of the FIPS codes for USA ocean ports. For example, "PORT_New Orleans, PORT_Houston".

What I have for now: I have all the lat & lon for the port. I know I can reverse geocoding from lat & lon to FIPS, but I am still interested in other methods.

Comment: Where did you get those two codes? Googling finds no useful results, and this type of stuff is usually online.

Answer (score 3):

Census' [2015 State, County, Minor Civil Division, and Incorporated Place FIPS Codes](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/geographies/2015/all-geocodes-v2015.xlsx) (XLSX) spreadsheet or this [list compiled by the FCC](https://transition.fcc.gov/oet/info/maps/census/fips/fips.txt) that lists state and locality codes.
If I understand correctly, this way you can skip the steps of finding out the ports' state, getting its FIPS code, then finding the ports' FIPS code within that state.

Here is the [Census' FIPS Codes for States and Localities](https://www.census.gov/prod/techdoc/cbp/95-96cd/fips-st.pdf), however it is a PDF and (at least for me) requires more work then text/spreadsheet formats.

[NGA has a list that includes both locality name and the State of the ports](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/RSD/coastal/projects/coastal/ports_list.html).